# When scrolling, NestedScrollView - Floating Action Button moves to the right

Tags: java, android

How do I make the Nested Scroll View - Floating Action Button move to the right when scrolling?
I tried it:

```
while (NSView.getScrollY() > 1 && NSView.getHeight() > 1) {
        bottomAppBar.setFabAlignmentMode(BottomAppBar.FAB_ALIGNMENT_MODE_END);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this solution

```
((CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) fab.getLayoutParams()).gravity = Gravity.END;
```

Comment: FAB went out of bounds BotomAppBar